# Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Integrated authentication Access vba

Tags: sql-server, vba

I am trying to connect to SQL Server on the internet using VBA TCP/IP. First thing that I did was to attach tables using DSN Less connection:

```
stConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=" & stServer & ";DATABASE=" & stDatabase & ";UID=" & stUsername & ";PWD=" & stPassword
 Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(stLocalTableName, 0, stRemoteTableName, stConnect)
```

This is working perfectly fine and I can now use Access linked tables to view my table contents.

But when I try to create an ADODB connection:

```
  Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
  cn.ConnectionTimeout = 60
  cn.CommandTimeout = 90
  cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=" & stServer & ";Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=" & stDatabase & ";UID=" & stUsername & ";PWD=" & stPassword & ";Data Provider=SQLOLEDB.1"
```

With the variables parsed the above connection string looks something like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0;Persist Security Info=False;Data Source=42.133.12.12,1433;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=MYDB;UID=MYDB_USER;PWD=MYDB_PASSWORD;Data Provider=SQLOLEDB.1
```

I get the error:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
> with Integrated authentication.

I have looked at various places online but have not found any solutions.

Comment: Does it work if you remove Integrated Security=SSPI from the connection string?

Comment: It does! Please add your answer below so that I can mark it as right answer

Answer (score 1):

Remove 'Integraged Security=SSPI' from your connection string.  You are specifying to use integrated security in addition to a username and password in the connection.